# Java - Pattern.compile() doesn't work with getting a regex string from object

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a regex to see if an url matches the criteria I have set for it. The problem I have is that I want the regex to be defined beforehand (in the frontend) and saved in aan object. I suspect that's where it goes wrong and it won't be able to compile the Pattern correctly. Let me give an example:

```
String url = "https://www.website-example.com/regex/80243/somemorechars"

if (Pattern.compile("regex/\\d{5}").matcher(url).find()) {
    System.out.println("Url found");
}
```

The above example will print "Url found" and there won't be any problems.
Now for the example that gives me the problems:

```
// Imagine the below object that will be created at my Angular frontend, send to the backend and saved:

@Entity()
@Table(name = "REGEXOBJ")
public class RegexObj{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "regex_gen")
    @TableGenerator(name = "regex_gen", table = "ama_sequence", pkColumnValue = "Regex")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    // some other fields I need

    @Column(name = "REGEX", nullable = false)
    private String regex;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getters and setters for the other fields

    public String getRegex() {
        return regex;
    }

    public void setRegex(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }
}
// =================================================== //

public boolean checkUrl(RegexObj regexObj) {
    String url = "https://www.website-example.com/regex/80243/somemorechars"

    if (Pattern.compile(regexObj.getRegex()).matcher(url).find()) {
        System.out.println("Url found");
    }
}
```

Now the url won't be matched to the regex, problably because the String is 'flat' and the '\\d{5}' part won't be seen as regex anymore. Is there a way around this to make it work?

EDIT - Added a simplified version of the class I use

Comment: We would need to see `RegexObj` to answer that.

Comment: For me it works fine. (getRegex() of regex object is a simple getter).

Comment: Cant you treat your input regex as a string and use Pattern.compile(myRegex).matcher.... ?

Comment: Nothing happens to a String if you just pass it to a field. It will be the same String. The problem lies within RegexObj class.

Comment: The problem is likely occuring in the place where the Regex string is set on the RegexObj. What is the value of regexObj.getRegex() right before you try to match?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The problem occured in fact while saving the object that was sent from the frontend. Where I set the string as "regex/\\d{5}" via an input field at the frontend it got saved as "regex/\\\\d{5}". Changing it to "regex/\d{5}" in my input field fixed the issue!